# how to disable aptana internal browser

Tags: php, browser, aptana

php file and when i run it , it runs in the Internal web browser in aptana , while when I run blabla.html it runs through firefox , I just want the php file to run just like the html , and disable that annoying Internal browser.

also would like to know what's the difference between (aptana) http://127.0.0.1:8000/blabla.php and (xampp) http://localhost/blabla.php

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a programming question. There's no code involved in changing the user settings. Anyway: http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Setting_up_your_web_browser_configuration - Look around there.

And the difference between your two webservers is the port number :8000. The name "localhost" references 127.0.0.1, too. As for any configuration differences, you should consult phpinfo() on each.

Comment: yes, my apologies for the question :)
and thanks for the answer about local host :)

Comment: @ismail marmoush: The XAMPP server probably hasn't the debug module from Aptanas PHP interpreter installed. But if the versions match, you might just copy that one over. (But also look out for php.ini settings and connecting Aptana to it.)